# A TypeScript GUID class?

Tags: typescript, uuid, guid

Does anyone know of a good, solid, implementation of C# like GUID (UUID) in TypeScript?

Could do it myself but figured I'd spare my time if someone else done it before.

Comment: @Briguy37's answer in [Stack Overflow: How to create a GUID / UUID in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8809472/2626313) is my favorite

Comment: Should be closed as Duplicate, not as 'off-topic"

Answer (score 218, accepted):

## Updated Answer

This is now something you can do natively in JavaScript/TypeScript with `crypto.randomUUID()`.

Here's an example generating 20 UUIDs.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    let id = crypto.randomUUID();
    console.log(id);
}
```

## Original Answer

There is an implementation in my [TypeScript utilities](https://github.com/Steve-Fenton/TypeScriptUtilities) based on JavaScript GUID generators.

Here is the code:

```js
class Guid {
  static newGuid() {
    return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
      var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0,
        v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8);
      return v.toString(16);
    });
  }
}

// Example of a bunch of GUIDs
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  var id = Guid.newGuid();
  console.log(id);
}
```

Please note the following:

C# GUIDs are guaranteed to be unique. This solution is *very likely* to be unique. There is a huge gap between "very likely" and "guaranteed" and you don't want to fall through this gap.

JavaScript-generated GUIDs are great to use as a temporary key that you use while waiting for a server to respond, but I wouldn't necessarily trust them as the primary key in a database. If you are going to rely on a JavaScript-generated GUID, I would be tempted to check a register each time a GUID is created to ensure you haven't got a duplicate (an issue that has come up in the Chrome browser in some cases).

Comment: Why are you generating GUIDs with the first character of the 3rd group always '4'?

Comment: @PaulGorbas See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier - this 4 indicates a kind of GUID version. The 4 indicates it is not MAC-address bases but pseudo-random and might not be cryptographically safe.

Comment: "C# GUIDs" are no more or no less unique than the ones produced by your function. A collision is so extremely unlikely that you can absolutely rely on their uniqueness. You can of course use it as a primary key and checking a registry is not helpful. This implementation is not cryptographically secure, though. So values may be predictable. But that's not a problem of uniqueness.

Comment: Note to potential editors of this answer: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code

Comment: If you are using tslint and it complains about the bitwise operators https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34578677/how-to-ignore-a-particular-directory-or-file-for-tslint/46449169#46449169 check that.

Comment: If you are using tslint, you can also just add braces around (r&0x3)|0x8

Comment: Not sure why but I ran jasmine test of let guid1=makeGuid(); let guid2=makeGuid(); and the two were the same.  it changes in each Jasmine test, but not on each run.

Comment: one reason of collision is when GUIDs are generated from different machines at the same time. Mac based GUIDs avoids collisions in those cases

Comment: This answer seems incomplete: the OP asked for a C# like class which should contain implementations such as `Empty` and `TryParse`.

Comment: The Updated Answer only works in secure browser contexts.

Answer (score 15):

I found this https://typescriptbcl.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest

here is [the Guid version](https://typescriptbcl.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#TypeScript.BCL/System/Guid.ts) they have in case the link does not work later.

```
module System {
    export class Guid {
        constructor (public guid: string) {
            this._guid = guid;
        }

        private _guid: string;

        public ToString(): string {
            return this.guid;
        }

        // Static member
        static MakeNew(): Guid {
            var result: string;
            var i: string;
            var j: number;

            result = "";
            for (j = 0; j < 32; j++) {
                if (j == 8 || j == 12 || j == 16 || j == 20)
                    result = result + '-';
                i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16).toString(16).toUpperCase();
                result = result + i;
            }
            return new Guid(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sadly this one doesn't set the mandatory bit patters for random UUID's, the first digit in the third segment must be 4, that's the UUID version number, and the first digit in the fourth segment must use the bitmask 10xx, meaning only the values 8, 9, A and B are allowed in that position.

Wiki URL: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_.28random.29

Comment: +1 for pasting in the source code, because the link to that site no longer has any typescript files and the JS  files they do host does not look like the code you posted.

Comment: @PaulGorbas it does. I added the link for completeness