# How to ignore a particular directory or file for tslint?

Tags: javascript, ide, typescript, webstorm, tslint

The IDE being used is WebStorm 11.0.3, the tslint is configured and works, but, it hangs because it tries to parse large *.d.ts library files.

Is there a way to ignore a particular file or directory?

Answer (score 239, accepted):

**Update for [tslint v5.8.0](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/releases/tag/5.8.0)**

As mentioned by [Saugat Acharya](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47039832/511215), you can now update **tslint.json** CLI Options:

```
{
  "extends": "tslint:latest",
  "linterOptions": {
      "exclude": [
          "bin",
          "lib/*generated.js"
      ]
  }
}
```

More information [in this pull request](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/pull/2409).

---

This feature has been introduced with [tslint 3.6](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/releases/tag/3.6.0-dev.1)

```
tslint \"src/**/*.ts\" -e \"**/__test__/**\"
```

You can now add --exclude (or -e) see [PR](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/pull/1006) here.

**CLI**

```
usage: tslint [options] file ...

Options:

-c, --config          configuration file
--force               return status code 0 even if there are lint errors
-h, --help            display detailed help
-i, --init            generate a tslint.json config file in the current working directory
-o, --out             output file
-r, --rules-dir       rules directory
-s, --formatters-dir  formatters directory
-e, --exclude         exclude globs from path expansion
-t, --format          output format (prose, json, verbose, pmd, msbuild, checkstyle)  [default: "prose"]
--test                test that tslint produces the correct output for the specified directory
-v, --version         current version
```

you are looking at using

```
-e, --exclude         exclude globs from path expansion
```

Comment: do you know how to exclude multiple paths?

Comment: repeat the exclude argument several times

Comment: Small correction to the update: it should be `linterOptions` and not `cliOptions`

Comment: It's also worth to mention that the glob patterns inside the exclude directory shall be relative to the `tslint.json`

Answer (score 93):

Currently using Visual Studio Code and the command to disable tslint is

```
/* tslint:disable */
```

Something to note. The disable above disables ALL tslint rules on that page. If you want to disable a specific rule you can specify one/multiple rules.

```
/* tslint:disable comment-format */
/* tslint:disable:rule1 rule2 rule3 etc.. */
```

Or enable a rule

```
/* tslint:enable comment-format */
```

[More in depth on TSLint rule flags](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/rule-flags/)

Comment: from all of the answers, this is the only one that worked. thanks!

Comment: For example, `/* tslint:disable:TS2322 */` did not work. Are you sure that you can ignore rules with your second code block?

Comment: You might need // instald of /* */ that link has some in depth rule, rules

Answer (score 27):

In addition to Michael's answer, consider a second way: adding [linterOptions.exclude](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/configuration/) to tslint.json

For example, you may have `tslint.json` with following lines:

```
{
  "linterOptions": {
    "exclude": [
      "someDirectory/*.d.ts"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 19):

Starting from `tslint v5.8.0` you can set an `exclude` property under your `linterOptions` key in your `tslint.json` file:

```
{
  "extends": "tslint:latest",
  "linterOptions": {
      "exclude": [
          "bin",
          "**/__test__",
          "lib/*generated.js"
      ]
  }
}
```

More information on this [here](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/pull/2409).

Comment: This should be marked as the correct (and updated Nov-2017) answer.

Comment: The correct way to do this is to replace `cliOptions` with `linterOptions`.

Answer (score 15):

I had to use the **/* syntax to exclude the files in a folder:

```
    "linterOptions": {
        "exclude": [
          "src/auto-generated/**/*",
          "src/app/auto-generated/**/*"
        ]
    },
```

Answer (score 10):

As an addition

To disable **all rules for the next line** `// tslint:disable-next-line`

To disable **specific rules for the next line**: `// tslint:disable-next-line:rule1 rule2...`

To disable **all rules for the current line**: `someCode(); // tslint:disable-line`

To disable **specific rules for the current line**: `someCode(); // tslint:disable-line:rule1`

Answer (score 9):

There [are](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/188) [others](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2013/issues/667) who encountered the problem. Unfortunately, there is only an open issue for excluding files: https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/73

So I'm afraid the answer is no.

Answer (score 6):

linterOptions is currently only handled by the CLI.
If you're not using CLI then depending on the code base you're using you'll need to set the ignore somewhere else. webpack, tsconfig, etc

Answer (score 4):

Can confirm that on version tslint 5.11.0 it works by modifying lint script in package.json by defining exclude argument:

```
"lint": "ng lint --exclude src/models/** --exclude package.json"
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Were you referring to some other answer, or did you simply wanted to provide an alternative answer to the question?

Answer (score 4):

add the section in your code example

```json
"linterOptions": {
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules/**/*.",
    "db/**/*.",
    "integrations/**/*."
  ]
},
```