# WebStorm formatter isn't good with TSLint

Tags: typescript, ide, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, tslint

I am working with TypeScript in WebStorm for quiet a while, and recently I added TSLint to my setup in order to write better code. I successfully integrated it into the IDE (WebStorm 2016) but I have a bad experience with the IDE formatter combining the TSLint formatting rules.

For example I write:

```
let bar: foo;  // fine by tslint standarts
```

And then I press <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + L</kbd> to format everything automatically and I get:

```
let bar:foo; // without space between the variable ":"
             // and its type the tslint complains
```

I haven't found any solution on the web and couldn't find a manual way to change this behaviour in the IDE.

Any help will be much appreciated ! :)

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34578677/how-to-ignore-a-particular-directory-or-file-for-tslint

Answer (score 4):

**update:** since the version 2016.3 the path is: **Settings > Editor > Code Style > TypeScript**

Go to: **Settings > Code Style > TypeScript**

Go to the **Spaces** tab and scroll down to **Other**

The last 2 options should do the trick:

- Before type reference colon ':'
- After type reference colon ':'

Check one or both, depending on what you want.

[image: Screenshot of the settings menu]

Comment: just note: default will be changed in WS2016.3 to match the tslint settings.