# How to ignore *.d.ts files when using tslint?

Tags: typescript, tslint

I want to add tslint to my workflow. I installed it via:

```
npm install tslint tslint-config-ms-recommended --save-dev
```

And my `tslint.json` looks like:

```
{
    "extends": "tslint-config-ms-recommended"
}
```

Yet when I run:

```
./node_modules/.bin/tslint src/**/*.ts
```

it also checks a lot of definitely typed files, e.g.:

```
src/interfaces/highland.d.ts[621, 1]: space indentation expected
src/interfaces/highland.d.ts[622, 1]: space indentation expected
src/interfaces/highland.d.ts[635, 1]: space indentation expected
```

polluting the output.

I want to check only my `*.ts` files and am looking for a way to ignore the other types.

I saw that there was a `--exclude` option, yet it still shows the d.ts files when I run:

```
./node_modules/.bin/tslint src/**/*.ts --exclude src/**/*.d.ts
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34578677/how-to-ignore-a-particular-directory-or-file-for-tslint

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The exclude option either requires a `=`, hence:

```
tslint src/**/*.ts --exclude=src/**/*.d.ts
```

or wrapping the ignore part into quotes:

```
tslint src/**/*.ts --exclude "src/**/*.d.ts"
```

will work as expected.

Comment: Another option is to use the following regex: `src/**/*[^.d$].ts`

Answer (score 3):

A very simple solution is to create a `.eslintignore` as follows:

```
*.d.ts
```

Include any other files you wish to ignore, for example:

```
node_modules
.storybook
dist
*.d.ts
```