# Exclude *.d.ts files in tslint

Tags: typescript, tslint

I'm aware of [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39572614/how-to-ignore-d-ts-files-when-using-tslint) and the [request on github](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/73), but it seems to not work for me. I tried these options:

```
tslint src/services/**/*.ts --exclude=src/services/**/*.d.ts

... --exclude "src/services/**/*.d.ts"

... --exclude src/services/**/*.d.ts

... --exclude "src/services/**/*[^.d$].ts"
```

and also using the shorthand of the `--exclude` option: `-e`, but I still get the `*.d.ts` files linted.

Comment: Your first 3 lines seem to be excluding all the source files themselves, your last line seem to have an incorrect regex. Have you tried `--exclude "**/*.d.ts"` ?

Comment: @zeh, yeah, sorry, it was just a typo here in the post. In the shell I use the command correctly. :)

Comment: `tslint "src/services/**/*.ts" --exclude "**/*.d.ts"` should work. Use double quotes around both arguments just to play it safe. If this doesn't work, can you verify what version of tslint you're using with `tslint -v`?