# How to ignore/exclude some files/directory from linting in angular cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli, tslint

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42241654/angular-cli-exclude-files-directory-for-ng-test-code-coverage)

I am running the following command to linting my angular2 typeScript code.

```
ng lint
```

It is proving all the linting error nicely.

But I want my vendor folder (let say "src/app/quote/services/generated/**/*") should not get included at the time of lining.

I know this can be done with tslint command as follows ([Reference Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34578677/how-to-ignore-a-particular-directory-or-file-for-tslint))

```
tslint \"src/**/*.ts\" -e \"**/__test__/**\"
```

But in angular cli what will be the parameter? How to exclude some files from tslint?

Note: My Angular Cli version is : @angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.0

Answer (score 64, accepted):

From **Angular6+**, `.angular-cli.json` has been replaced by `angular.json`, but you can still add the exclude path in its `lint` part.

```
"lint": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
      "options": {
        "tsConfig": [
          "src/tsconfig.app.json",
          "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
        ],
        "exclude": [
          "**/node_modules/**"      // excluded directories
        ]
      }
    }
```

---

According to the angular-cli [issue#5063](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5063), you can add the exclude path in **`.angular-cli.json`** like this:

```
"lint": [
{
  "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
  "exclude": "**/node_modules/**/*"   // the node_modules for example
}]
```

Comment: Actually, I found that the solution for me was to edit the `exclude` property under `./src/tsconfig.app.json`, instead of `.angular-cli.json`.

Answer (score 13):

Figured out it HAS to be a blob pattern..

If you want multiple files/directories just use an array in your `.angular-cli.json`

```
"exclude": [
 "**/*whatever.pipe.ts", 
 "**/*whatever_else.component.ts"
]
```

Comment: Actually, I found that the solution for me was to edit the `exclude` property under `./src/app/tsconfig.app.json`, instead of `.angular-cli.json`.

Answer (score 1):

**Recent answer (10/2022 - eslint v8) :**

Quote from eslint official documentation :

> You can tell ESLint to ignore specific files and directories using
> ignorePatterns in your config files. ignorePatterns patterns follow
> the same rules as .eslintignore. Please see the .eslintignore file
> documentation to learn more.

If you have an `.eslintrc.json` config file, you can set `ignorePatterns` option as following :

```
{
    "ignorePatterns": ["your_file.js", "/your_dir/*.js"],
    "rules": {
        //...
    }
}
```

If you don't have the `.eslintrc.json` file, check the link below to find a suitable solution for your setup.

**Ressources & useful links you might want to check for more information**
https://eslint.org/docs/latest/user-guide/configuring/ignoring-code

Answer (score -1):

Your angular-cli.json file would be like this-

```
"lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    }
  ]
```

You need to remove the lint path for "src/tsconfig.spec.json". So either remove the second object or comment it.
Your updated lint array should be like this-

```
"lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    }
  ]
```