# How to run a tslint script while ignoring specific file types

Tags: tslint, npm-scripts

I've got TSLint running nicely in my IDE and everything is great! However when I run `npm run tslint` it throws errors on some of my `.svg` and `.scss` files. It shouldn't be running on that and it doesn't run those in my IDE so what's up?

Here's my `package.json` script:

```
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint ./src/*",
  },
```

Can I edit that script to ignore `.svg` and `.scss` files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to ignore a particular directory or file for tslint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34578677/how-to-ignore-a-particular-directory-or-file-for-tslint)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to only lint `.ts` and `.tsx` files (or just `.ts` if you're not on React).

```
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint ./src/**/*.ts ./src/**/*.tsx",
  },
```

Comment: `tslint` utilizes the [glob](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/blob/master/package.json#LC37) package for file globbing, so presumably this could be refactored to utilize [brace expansion](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob). For instance: `"lint": "tslint ./src/**/*.{ts,tsx}",`