# GUID / UUID type in typescript

Tags: types, typescript, guid, uuid

I have this function:

```
function getProduct(id: string){    
    //return some product 
}
```

where id is actually GUID. Typescript doesn't have guid type. Is it possible create type `GUID` manually?

```
function getProduct(id: GUID){    
    //return some product 
}
```

so if instead `'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'` will be some `'notGuidbutJustString'` then I will see typescript compilation error.

**Update:** as David Sherret said: there is no way to ensure a string value based on regex or some other function at compile time but it is possible do all the checks in one place at run time.

Comment: The relevant issue is at [Suggestion: Regex-validated string type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6579).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A typescript Guid class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26501688/a-typescript-guid-class)

Comment: You could use a type alias, but it wouldn't provide any compile time checks. Just a hint to the developer. `type Guid = string;`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You could create a wrapper around a string and pass that around:

```
class GUID {
    private str: string;

    constructor(str?: string) {
        this.str = str || GUID.getNewGUIDString();
    }

    toString() {
        return this.str;
    }

    private static getNewGUIDString() {
        // your favourite guid generation function could go here
        // ex: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8809472/188246
        let d = new Date().getTime();
        if (window.performance && typeof window.performance.now === "function") {
            d += performance.now(); //use high-precision timer if available
        }
        return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, (c) => {
            let r = (d + Math.random() * 16) % 16 | 0;
            d = Math.floor(d/16);
            return (c=='x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8)).toString(16);
        });
    }
}

function getProduct(id: GUID) {    
    alert(id); // alerts "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
}

const guid = new GUID("xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx");
getProduct(guid); // ok
getProduct("notGuidbutJustString"); // errors, good

const guid2 = new GUID();
console.log(guid2.toString()); // some guid string
```

**Update**

Another way of doing this is to use a brand:

```
type Guid = string & { _guidBrand: undefined };

function makeGuid(text: string): Guid {
  // todo: add some validation and normalization here
  return text as Guid;
}

const someValue = "someString";
const myGuid = makeGuid("ef3c1860-5ce6-47af-a13d-1ed72f65b641");

expectsGuid(someValue); // error, good
expectsGuid(myGuid); // ok, good

function expectsGuid(guid: Guid) {
}
```

Comment: but this wrapper moves my problem in other place, because I still can do: const guid = new GUID("notGuidbutJustString"). Sure I can add some runtime checking in GUID class but I want see error before application starts...

Comment: @Rajab there's no way to ensure a string value based on regex or some other function at compile time. I would recommend written unit tests to catch this problem.

Comment: It's a pity. Maybe this will change in the future but anyway your answer is helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I have created a little Typescript [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid-generator-ts) on [GitHub](https://github.com/BuZZ-dEE/uuid-generator-ts/tree/master/src) including unit tests.

Answer (score 4):

I think one should extend a bit on the answer by David Sherret. 
Like this:

```
// export 
class InvalidUuidError extends Error {
    constructor(m?: string) {
        super(m || "Error: invalid UUID !");

        // Set the prototype explicitly.
        Object.setPrototypeOf(this, InvalidUuidError.prototype);
    }

}


// export 
class UUID 
{
    protected m_str: string;

    constructor(str?: string) {
        this.m_str = str || UUID.newUuid().toString();

        let reg:RegExp = new RegExp("[A-F0-9]{8}-[A-F0-9]{4}-[A-F0-9]{4}-[A-F0-9]{4}-[A-F0-9]{12}", "i")
        if(!reg.test(this.m_str))
            throw new InvalidUuidError();
    }

    toString() {
        return this.m_str;
    }

    public static newUuid(version?:number) :UUID
    {
        version = version || 4;


        // your favourite guid generation function could go here
        // ex: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8809472/188246
        let d = new Date().getTime();
        if (window.performance && typeof window.performance.now === "function") {
            d += performance.now(); //use high-precision timer if available
        }
        let uuid:string = ('xxxxxxxx-xxxx-' + version.toString().substr(0,1) + 'xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx').replace(/[xy]/g, (c) => {
            let r = (d + Math.random() * 16) % 16 | 0;
            d = Math.floor(d/16);
            return (c=='x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8)).toString(16);
        });

        return new UUID(uuid);
    }
}


function getProduct(id: UUID) {    
    alert(id); // alerts "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
}


const guid2 = new UUID();
console.log(guid2.toString()); // some guid string


const guid = new UUID("xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx");
getProduct(guid); // ok
getProduct("notGuidbutJustString"); // errors, good
```

Answer (score 1):

I really like @DavidSherret's updated version using the idiomatic approach for strongly typed primitives, namely via a branded type / tagged union type (+1).

Expanding upon it by adding a type parameter for the brand, one can even tie the ID to a specific entity or object type (like the "Product" in the OP's question):

```
type OptionalRecord = Record<string, unknown> | undefined

type Uuid<T extends OptionalRecord = undefined> = string & { __uuidBrand: T }

type Product = {
    id: Uuid<Product>
    name: string
}

type ProductId = Product['id']

function uuid<T extends OptionalRecord = undefined>(value: string) {
    return value as Uuid<T>
}

function productId(value: string) {
    return uuid<Product>(value)
}

function funcWithProductIdArg(productId: ProductId) {
    // do something
    return productId
}

const concreteProductId = productId('123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000')

// compiles
funcWithProductIdArg(concreteProductId)

// Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ProductId'.
//  Type 'string' is not assignable to type '{ __uuidBrand: Product; }'.(2345)
//
// @ts-expect-error Not a ProductId.
funcWithProductIdArg('123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000')
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AhgGwEoQMZICcATKAXih32IB4BnYAhFAcwBooBXFAaxSQHcUAPigAfTiiIQAZkwhEAUAtCQoAVQ4Ii1ACpQIAD2ARJtWPGTpseQiXJcpslPJHl6jFlABkUAN5QAfQCOTSIAIQI0SQAuKD0AXyUVaAAFAiQiDlxgMj8FKAKoLViNLWo0jKzgIXzC9ABbCFj3JmYFROVwVPTM7IBJOygK3uAAbQByLXGAXSVpLmzLTlDdfSMTIjM4RFRMSltchxk5IiEACgA3TA4mqBaWAEo8wqgCCGAOAhQoK4wbqDQZlK2h0NQ68xQi1QUDAPSqA0u11u92YT18tQKbw+X2WZWGVXOvxuD3acwWO2+ENwAHUEMAABb4-pEACCBGYZ1hlWZsSZwAGaIxUAA9MKoEQkHckI0Ga0hVjPt8uSMBqSFPgUPQoBrcFiIHyBrllfCiGdxgBGABMAGYIAAWACsADYAOwAWggAA4AJwAIzdVqI1rdaEdTrddstTqd5rt5pddoADMnxiSFKLtdKwAgMBBaAoqbSGQbWeyzjq9SW0xm2cwOI0UDkkNIoMkoOMUeMimY+DlAbQEMx0L7c63JWA0JEZRACFBm62uu2S+MAHTpsVxRcdhitLsIHtIPu0AdDtAj6DASVt8b+IIhLQRKJEXlw7IAbig8VXZxtjpJovXKAAAFgFoD0DEgbIPQIdJZwAOUPAEhlffkiDXQs6UZFCBlrM0rVtMN3S9P0A0tIMQzDCMoxjOME2TRNUwUIA)

Answer (score 0):

Adding my answer here, which is built on the answers above:

```
// use a brand to create a tagged type. Horrible hack but best we can do
export type UUID = string & { __uuid: void };

// uuid regex
const UUID_REGEX = /^[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\b-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\b-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\b-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\b-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}$/;

// type guard to assert a string is a valid uuid
export function isUUID(uuid: string): uuid is UUID {
  return UUID_REGEX.test(uuid);
}
```

The trick is to use [typescript type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) to assert a string is a valid UUID.

Unlike a simple `type UUID = string` type alias, typescript won't silently coerce strings to UUID.

You'll need to check a string is a valid UUID before using it where a UUID is expected.

Here's an example:

```
function needUUID(uuid: UUID) {
  console.log(uuid)
}

const input = ''

// this won't compile, we don't know whether input is a valid UUID
needUUID(input)

if (isUUID(input) {
  // this compiles successfully, we've verified that input is a valid UUID
  needUUID(input)
} else {
  // this fails to compile, we know input is _not_ a valid uuid
  needUUID(input)
}
```

Comment: Short and sweet for just validation. But once you are adding a type... might just as well give it constructor and other stuff (like in the older/more voted answers...), it might still come in handy down the road if you need to generate a uuid rather than just validating one.