# GUID type in typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, guid

Is GUID available in typescript?

I have manually create GUID by using `JavaScript` code.

```
function guid() {
  function s4() {
    return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
      .toString(16)
      .substring(1);
  }
  return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' +
    s4() + '-' + s4() + s4() + s4();
}
```

---

> But am seeing typescript have `AAGUID` type. but I don't know what is the use of this type. Is it related with GUID or any data type's are available to create GUID in typescript?

Comment: `AAGUID` is just an alias for `string`, so… meh.

Comment: I think there is no any such GUID available

Comment: What you want is a regex-validated string type. Which is [still in discussion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6579).
As a workaround you can create a wrapper class like the one suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37144720/2419531).

Comment: Same as we can create a common method which I have tried. That's fine.  But my question is! Is  GUID is available or not

Comment: @deceze , then what is the difference between String and AAGUID :( ?

Comment: Nothing. It's just used for clarification of what "kind" of string it is.

Comment: Can I ask a new question for that? can you explain briefly on there?

Comment: @RameshRajendran it's just a string.. String Type.. There are a few explanations around for this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/30212946/1606432 Another GUI class : github.com/Steve-Fenton/TypeScriptUtilities/blob/master/Guid you can see `v.toString(16)`