# How to create GUID in angular-2?

Tags: angular, typescript

in my application i need to create GUID, that GUID will be work as cookies, so anybody knows how to create GUID in angular-2/typescript or using any angular2 dependency/library.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/105074/1876949

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate UUID with angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45754907/how-to-generate-uuid-with-angular-2)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26501688/a-typescript-guid-class), or try this npm [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-uuid).

Comment: Also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/create-guid-uuid-in-javascript, hope it will work.

Comment: Seems like that package produces guids that don't conform to the spec, maybe fit for your purpose but be aware. Have a look at the issues in the git repo for details.

Answer (score 23):

You even can use npm to generate this for you. Follow this :

```
npm i guid-typescript --save
```

And to utilize in your code :

```
import { Guid } from 'guid-typescript';
export class GuidExample {
    public id: Guid;
    constructor() {
        this.id = Guid.create(); // ==> b77d409a-10cd-4a47-8e94-b0cd0ab50aa1
    }
}
```

Comment: pacakge [`uuid`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) is more popular; `npm i uuid @types/uuid`

Answer (score 5):

You can use this code to generate your own GUID:

```
class GuidGenerator {
    static newGuid() {
      return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
        var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0,
        v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8);
        return v.toString(16);
      });
    }
}
```

Comment: Should not use Math.random() - Please refer: https://bocoup.com/blog/random-numbers