# How to generate UUID with angular 2?

Tags: angular, uuid

I'm using Angular 2 for a signup form:
first name, last name, email and password.

After submit, the data is being stored via API call in a database (nodeJs and mongo) and generates a JWT Token which is sent back to the client.

Now I should add/generate an UUID (Universal Unique Identifier). As I never have done this kind of feature before, I need an approach and idea/solution how to achieve this... would the JWT Token be a kind of alternative to UUID? If yes, this would be enough.

Otherwise I would prefer to avoid any big changes on the form or its functionality.

I Have been searching, but didn't find a useful solution. I tried the npm package `angular2-uuid`, but after installing it as dependency, the `ng build -prod` throws an error which isn't clear.

```
import { UUID } from 'angular2-uuid';
....
let uuid = UUID.UUID();
```

**Error:**

> ERROR in ./~/@angular/flex-layout/@angular/flex-layout.es5.js Module
>        build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>        '/Users/username/dev/app/node_modules/@angular/flex-
>       layout/@angular/flex-layout.es5.js' @ 
>       ./src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts 25:0-44 @ ./src/main.ts @
>        multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts

Any idea or Hint please?

Comment: `throws an error which isn't clear` ... `Any idea or Hint please?` Hint: what's the error?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney: Yes, you are right. sorry. here is the errror:`ERROR in ./~/@angular/flex-layout/@angular/flex-layout.es5.js
Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/username/dev/app/node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/@angular/flex-layout.es5.js'
 @ ./src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts 25:0-44
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts`
The error has actually nothing to do with the installed `UUID`. When I uninstall it, then the error goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue fixed. Solution: I found out that when I did install the package `angular2-uuid` via command-line, it was automatically stored in `package.json` directly before/over the package: `@angular/flex-layout`.

As the error was in a way not clear, I just did remove it to other position in the: `package.json` and the error is gone. everything works fine.

Comment: `angular2-uuid` is unmaintained. Use `uuid` package instead.

Comment: @Vishnudev: After 2 years, you're trying to make too much noise on that! A short and a good comment would have been much better. I don't know how does it come to down vote this! I think some users just need to make noise and interact anyway!

Comment: I'm sorry if that hurt your feelings in any way. I just added the comment so that people who still come to the post won't get into a wrong answer. I'll up-vote if you'll update the answer :)

Answer (score 112):

It's downloaded as a part of Angular's dependency, use it like:

```
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';

@Component(..)
export class AppComponent {

  console.log('new uid: ', uuid());
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, it works!! I've created a [demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uuid-generation?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts), for future readers. Not sure if it's part of angular though, I think [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) package is being used.

Comment: Make sure to run `npm install --save @types/uuid` before execution.

Comment: @MenelaosKotsollaris you mean `--save-dev` or `-D`, so it is `npm install --save-dev @types/uuid` or `npm i -D @types/uuid` if you like the shortened format

Answer (score 2):

For Angular 11+

1. `npm i uuid`
2. In your component, at the top where your imports are, add `import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';`
3. To test this:

```
ngOnInit() {
  console.log('new uid: ', uuidv4());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this (`https://github.com/wulfsolter/angular2-uuid`)

As the doc say :

```
import { UuidService } from 'angular2-uuid';

constructor(private uuid: UuidService) //<-- pass it in contructor as service

const uuid = this.uuid.generate(); //<-- use it
```

Hope it helps you! ..as you can see it changed a little bit from what it report here (https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-uuid)