# How to represent Guid in typescript?

Tags: c#, typescript

let's say I have this C# class

```
public class Product
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public string ProductName { get; set; }
   public Decimal Price { get; set; }
   public int Level { get; set; }
}
```

The equivalent typescript would be something like:

```
export class Product {
  id: ???;
  productName: string;
  price: number;
  level: number;
}
```

How to represent Guid in typescript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A typescript Guid class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26501688/a-typescript-guid-class)

Comment: Would `string` work for you?

Comment: You might want to do `type Guid = string;`.

Comment: @BossRoss, your link shows how to generate a Guid in typescript. I'm not doing that. The backend will generate all the Guid. All I want is that typescript be able to parse the Guid into the right type.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Guids are usually represented as strings in Javascript, so the simplest way to represent the GUID is as a string. Usually when serialization to JSON occurs it is represented as a string, so using a string will ensure compatibility with data from the server.

To make the GUID different from a simple string, you could use branded types:

```
type GUID = string & { isGuid: true};
function guid(guid: string) : GUID {
    return  guid as GUID; // maybe add validation that the parameter is an actual guid ?
}
export interface Product {
    id: GUID;
    productName: string;
    price: number;
    level: number;
}

declare let p: Product;
p.id = "" // error
p.id = guid("guid data"); // ok
p.id.split('-') // we have access to string methods
```

This [article](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/01/15/typescript-flexible-nominal-typing/) has a bit more of a discussion on branded types. Also the typescript compiler uses branded types for [paths](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/8e8e879fc22e080f0c8fe69a73921899ab062c3f/src/compiler/types.ts#L54) which is similar to this use case.

Answer (score 20):

Another alternative is using following NPM package:

**guid-typescript** which you can find here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/guid-typescript

Then it will be just like this:

```
import { Guid } from "guid-typescript";

export class Product {
    id: Guid;
    productName: string;
    price: number;
    level: number;
}
```

Comment: Angular warns about this package as of the last few major versions. 
"[some-class] depends on 'guid-typescript'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts."

Answer (score 0):

For most of my use cases, I need to accept a deserialized string that comes from an API, but also generate new ids and validate them once they're on the client.

Both of the previous answers are great & each tackle a piece of the problem, where this gist combines the typing from the accepted answer and the spirit of the *guid-typescript* package:  https://gist.github.com/dperish/b9b2bbc6f10c686921c0f216bfe4cb40

```
class GuidFlavoring<FlavorT> {
  // tslint:disable-next-line: variable-name
  _type?: FlavorT;
}

/** A **guid** type, based on **string** */
type GuidFlavor<T, FlavorT> = T & GuidFlavoring<FlavorT>;

/** A **guid**-flavored string primitive, supported by factory methods in the **Guid** class
 */
export type guid = GuidFlavor<string, 'guid'>;

/** A container for factory methods, which support the **guid** type */
export class Guid {
  /** Specifies the RegExp necessary to validate **guid** values */
  private static validator: RegExp = new RegExp(
    '^[a-f0-9]{8}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{12}$',
    'i'
  );

  /** Generates a random, hyphenated **guid** value */
  static newGuid = (): guid =>
    [
      Guid.generateGuidSegment(2),
      Guid.generateGuidSegment(1),
      Guid.generateGuidSegment(1),
      Guid.generateGuidSegment(1),
      Guid.generateGuidSegment(3),
    ].join('-');

  /** Generates a new **guid**, with the empty/least possible value
   * @returns {guid} 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
   */
  static empty = (): guid => '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000';

  /** Generates a new **guid**, with the full/greatest possible value
   * @returns {guid} ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff
   */
  static full = (): guid => 'ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff';

  /** Evaluates whether the supplied **guid** is equal to the empty/least possible value */
  static isEmpty = (value: guid) => value === Guid.empty();

  /** Evaluates whether the supplied *guid* is equal to the empty/greatest possible value */
  static isFull = (value: guid) => value === Guid.full();

  /** Evaluates whether the supplied value is a valid **guid** */
  static isValid = (value: string | guid): boolean =>
    Guid.validator.test(value);

  /** Generates a specified number of double-byte segements for **guid** generation  */
  private static generateGuidSegment(count: number): string {
    let out = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      // tslint:disable-next-line:no-bitwise
      out += (((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000) | 0)
        .toString(16)
        .substring(1)
        .toLowerCase();
    }
    return out;
  }
}
```