# Is it possible to type check String Aliases in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Given this code:

```
type Firstname = string
type Surname  = string

const firstname: Firstname = "John";
const surname:Surname = "Smith"

function print(name: Firstname) {
    console.log(name)
}

/*
 * This should give a compile error
 */

print(surname);
```

Is it possible to disallow passing in a `Surname` when the function requires a `Firstname`?

Comment: Nominal typing is something TypeScript have on their roadmap. See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap and
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/202

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are looking for what is called branded types. In typescript type compatibility is decided structurally so the alias will not make types incompatible but we can make them structurally different using an intersection type and a unique symbol:

```
type Firstname = string & { readonly brand?: unique symbol }
type Surname = string & { readonly brand?: unique symbol }

const firstname: Firstname = "John"; // we can assign a string because brans is optional 
const surname: Surname = "Smith"

function print(name: Firstname) {
    console.log(name)
}

print(surname); // error unques symbol declarations are incompatible
```

Different variations on this may be useful but the basic idea is the same, you might find these similar answers useful : [guid definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49432350/how-to-represent-guid-in-typescript/49432424?s=2|33.3405#49432424), [index and position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49260143/how-do-you-emulate-nominal-typing-in-typescript/49260286?s=5|28.7138#49260286) , and [others](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A125734+%5Btypescript%5D+body%3Abranded+)

Comment: @corgrath added some links, hope they help :-)

Comment: It would most helpful to include in your answer the useful terminology related to this issue of "nominal typing" and "structural typing".