# How to define an opaque type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

If I recall correctly, in C++ you can define an an opaque type like this ...

```
class Foo;
```

... and use it like a handle e.g. when declaring function signatures ...

```
void printFoo(const Foo& foo);
```

Application code might then work with references-to-Foo or pointers-to-Foo without seeing the actual definition of Foo.

Is there anything similar in TypeScript -- how would you define an opaque type?

My problem is that if I define this ...

```
interface Foo {};
```

... then that's freely interchangeable with other similar types. Is there an idiom?

Comment: Do you look about the Generic Type ? I am not sure to really understand your question but it may help you.

Comment: I think you are looking for branded types: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49432350/how-to-represent-guid-in-typescript/49432424#49432424

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Yes that's it. Would you like to answer this question or shall I delete it instead?

Comment: @ChrisW I don't think any of the other branded type questions  reference opaque so it might be useful to add an answer to improve search-ability ... I'll add one once I'm out of a meeting

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to represent Guid in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49432350/how-to-represent-guid-in-typescript)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

That is because TypeScript type system is "structural", so any two types with the same shape will be assignable one to each other - as opposed to "nominal", where introducing a new name like `Foo` would make it non-assignable to a same-shape `Bar` type, and viceversa.

There's this [long standing issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/202) tracking nominal typings additions to TS.

One common approximation of opaque types in TS is using a unique tag to make any two types structurally different:

```
// opaque type module:
export type EUR = { readonly _tag: 'EUR' };
export function eur(value: number): EUR {
  return value as any;
}
export function addEuros(a: EUR, b: EUR): EUR {
  return ((a as any) + (b as any)) as any;
}

// usage from other modules:
const result: EUR = addEuros(eur(1), eur(10)); // OK
const c = eur(1) + eur(10) // Error: Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'EUR' and 'EUR'.
```

Even better, the tag can be encoded with a unique Symbol to make sure it is never accessed and used otherwise:

```
declare const tag: unique symbol;
export type EUR = { readonly [tag]: 'EUR' };
```

Note that these representation don't have any effect at runtime, the only overhead is calling the `eur` constructor.

[newtype-ts](https://github.com/gcanti/newtype-ts) provides generic utilities for defining and using values of types that behave similar to my examples above.

**Branded types**

Another typical use case is to keep the non-assignability only in one direction, i.e. deal with an `EUR` type which is assignable to `number`:

```
declare const a: EUR;
const b: number = a; // OK
```

This can be obtained via so called "branded types":

```
declare const tag: unique symbol
export type EUR = number & { readonly [tag]: 'EUR' };
```

See for instance this [usage in the `io-ts` library.](https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts/blob/b88a20cf978d042b93ca95f746bafa549b9343f8/src/index.ts#L1134-L1146)

Comment: see also this great [blog post about Branding vs. Flavoring](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/01/15/typescript-flexible-nominal-typing/)

Comment: A similar solution for branded types using enums : https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/main-1/nominaltyping