# What Typescript patterns exist to validate method parameters without affecting each method's implementation?

Tags: typescript, api-design

I'm building an API and would like to isolate the business logic into simple POTO "services" that deal with a single business concern.

The below examples deal with the concept of a `user`, which can have an `account`, which can have `notes` attached.

First a **naive example**:

```
class AccountService {
  addNote(userId:string, accountId:string, note:string) {
    NoteEntity.create({userId, accountId, note})
  }
}
```

This works, but presents a security problem: What if `accountId` is not owned by `userId`? So this method would allow the creation of a note with invalid ownership, violating my intention to contain business logic in the service layer.

So I add **validation**:

```
class AccountService {
  addNote(userId:string, accountId:string, note:string) {
    validateUserAndAccount(userId, accountId) // <- throws if IDs are not associated
    NoteEntity.create({userId, accountId, note})
  }
}
```

Now the method is secure. But that `validateUserAndAccount` function call will have to be copy-pasted across all methods, and probably also to other services that also deal with the `userId` and `accountId` concerns. It'll probably also be quite easy to forget to add that line because validation is not part of what the method really is about.

Can you suggest code-patterns that could extract that kind of validation behaviour, so it sits separate from the method's implementation? I'd like the validation to live in another layer and be composed or mixed into the service layer.

I did an experiment with **decorators**:

```
class AccountService {
  @validateUserAndAccount() // <- using Reflection and Regex-parsing it validates the signature and does runtime validation of the values
  addNote(userId:string, accountId:string, note:string) {
    NoteEntity.create({userId, accountId, note})
  }
}
```

This works fairly well, but testing becomes a pain because it's complex to mock out the validation:

```
const testSvc = new AccountService().addNote("1", "2", "foo")
// Fails until I go create a set of correctly configured entities,
// and allow database connection in the test.
// What was supposed to be a simple POTO service now has hidden database complexities :(
```

So I think I'm looking for a pattern that preserves the separation between validation and each method's implementation, but also maintains the simplicity of services being "just POTOs" without making testing them super complex.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

maybe Your problem related to structural nature of TS type system.

Please try next approach:

```js
type Nominal<T> = string & { __brand: T };

type UserID = Nominal<'UserID'>;
type AccountId= Nominal<'UserAccountID'>;

type User = {
    userId:UserID;
    accountId: AccountId;
}

class AccountService {
  addNote(userId:UserID, accountId:AccountId) {
      // some code
  }
}

const service = new AccountService();

const makeUserId = () => '123' as UserID;
const makeAccountId = () => '321' as AccountId;
const handleNote = service.addNote(makeUserId(), makeAccountId())
```

Now, if You will try to call `addNote` method with just simple strings, You will end up with compile error:

```js
service.addNote('some string', 'another string') // compile Error
```

More insformation You can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56737033/how-to-define-an-opaque-type-in-typescript)
Please let me know if You have any other questions