# Is it possible to create types that result from math operations in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, interface, typescript-types

I have some variables which are all numbers in Typescript and I want to make some calculations on them. I would like if possible to do something like this:

example:

```
type Newton = number;
type Mass = number;
type Acceleration = number;

type Second = number;
type Distance = number;
type Speed = number;


// Newton <- Mass * Acceleration
// Speed <- Distance / Second
```

so if I try to do this it will succeed:

```
const mass: Mass = 3;
const acceleration: Acceleration = 2;
const force: Newton = mass * acceleration // succeeds
```

but here should fail:

```
const distance: Distance = 3;
const time: Second = 2;
const speed: Speed = distance * time // Error: cannot bind type 'Distance x Second' to type 'Speed'
```

Is this somehow possible ?

Comment: Can't be done with numbers and built in math operators, but if custom objects and function calls are acceptable you could look into https://github.com/jscheiny/safe-units

Comment: TypeScript is *structurally*, not *nominally* typed, but see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56749647/3001761 for options.

Comment: @but-why this is not F# ))))