# How do I create an opaque type?

Tags: typescript

[ This is not [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56737033/how-to-define-an-opaque-type-in-typescript) ]

Observe the following code:

```
interface Machine<OpaqueType> {
    get(): OpaqueType,
    update(t: OpaqueType);
}

const f = <U, V>(uMachine: Machine<U>, vMachine: Machine<V>) => {
    const u = uMachine.get();
    vMachine.update(u);
}
```

That last line does not compile, saying “Argument of type 'U' is not assignable to parameter of type 'V'.  'V' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'U'.”

Exactamundo!  I have two machines, each can work on its own parts but not (without some deliberate coordination) on each other.

But the `<U, V>` stuff is superfluous.  The function does not care what the actual types are.  I would like to be able to write:

```
const f = (uMachine: Machine<unknown>, vMachine: Machine<unknown>) => {
    const u = uMachine.get();
    vMachine.update(u);
}
```

And have it **not** compile, since one unknown is not necessarily compatible with some other unknown.

Can I express this in Typescript?

**Edit:** the second one is *not* supposed to compile.   It’s wrong and I want the compiler to catch this.

Comment: In order to have `vMachine.update(u);` then `U` must extend `V`. But you haven't expressed that. That's easy to fix, see https://tsplay.dev/w1QVyw. Do you want me to write up that as an answer?

Comment: But the second part of this is weirder. `unknown` is fundamentally compatible with `unknown`. If a machine will only work with specific type, then you have to say what that type is. And two machine that both work with unknown are the _same type of machine_. Typescript is structural so two types of the same shape are indistinguishable. If you want to explore that, then we need mroe detail on what you mean here, and that's probably a whole other question.

Comment: The closest TypeScript has is `unique symbol` but that doesn't work programmatically so you can't use it.   TypeScript doesn't have first-class nominal types, let alone truly "opaque" or "unique" types, so I don't think you can get what you're looking for.  Using two unrelated generic types is a reasonable approach, but you've said it's "superfluous" so I guess the answer is just "no"?

Comment: @AlexWayne “If a machine will only work with specific type, then you have to say what that type is”.  That’s the whole point, I don’t want to say what that type is!  The function `f` does not know or care what the type is, I want it to work with “whatever the type is for the Machine I was given”.

Comment: I think I misunderstood. You don't literally mean the type `unknown`, but just a generic placeholder for any type which may or may not be compatible?

Comment: @AlexWayne Yes, it is an unknown type, but not the `unknown` type.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. In TypeScript, types are structural, compared "by value". Any type, including `any` or `unknown`, corresponds precisely to a set of values. What you want here is an imprecise type, a placeholder ‒ that's what generics are for. `<U, V>` may be superfluous to you, but it expresses exactly what you want ‒ that there are two unknown and unrelated types.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you're looking for not two but one generic type parameter?

```
const f = <U,>(uMachine: Machine<U>, vMachine: Machine<U>) => {
    const u = uMachine.get();
    vMachine.update(u);
}
```

The two machines can have whatever types they like as long as they're the same. But two different machines cannot coordinate with each other.

Comment: There's a problem with this. The common type may be too wide. https://tsplay.dev/WKr2ym The compiler is ok with a `string` being sent to the `update` method of a machine that expects `'abc'|'def'`

Comment: I am trying to make compilation _fail_, not succeed.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have `vMachine.update(u)`; then `U` must be assignable to `V`. You can express that in your generic by adding a constraint that `U` must extend `V`.

```
const f = <U extends V, V>(uMachine: Machine<U>, vMachine: Machine<V>) => {
    const u = uMachine.get();
    vMachine.update(u);
}
```

Now the `Machine<U>` which provides the value, must have an `OpaqueType` that `Machine<V>` can accept.

So now assuming you had these two machines, one of which takes union of string literals, and one of which takes any string:

```
declare const machineStringLiteral: Machine<'abc' | 'def'>
declare const machineAnyString: Machine<string>
```

This will do the following:

```
f(machineStringLiteral, machineAnyString) // fine
f(machineAnyString, machineStringLiteral) // type error
// Argument of type 'Machine<string>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Machine<"abc" | "def">'.
//   Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"abc" | "def"'.(2345)
```

Which seems exactly right because `string` cannot be assigned to `"abc" | "def"`

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLKIBaggHgPIAOcAjgK4QAqAngRAHzIDeAUMm8gOYRgAUAlAC5khEuWq0ANK3akCAEziQeYISLKUaEQcgBuAe2ByA3MwC+zZgj0gAzmGQxkAXmQ4AqsggAPSCDk3kADUJILoeUnQELBAIIUjo3Dc6EJ147DjMbBxAuj5nBhZ2ZCtbe1JnZAjMmIA6Ll4+EyLU6oga2QUlUkazCzkIBAAbOCgUErtkAFtWgGUwKFAOABlgSCg4QYyorIByOAAjBB3kAB9kHf6YHbpmfqGRsesJ6e2YgEEQKjmFkA4thJwdh+HBuMB4LwS30WKzWGxCEOwHy+80WeQA9GiHNhmGCEe9PlDfvDZijfjDoBt0ZiwJpPFAoHooMwgA)