# Typescript type alias let Intellisense show alias name, not source type

Tags: typescript, types, type-alias

Consider this short piece of code

```
type A = number;

declare function f(): A;

const a = f(); // `a` is number, not A
```

Why does TS show `a: number` instead of `a: A`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type aliases as their name suggests are just different names for another types. Type alias names are not something the compiler is guaranteed to preserve (unlike interfaces) and it applies a heuristic that gives the best user experience (in this case it arguably fails).

Also not that `A` and `number` are effectively the same type. If you want to ensure the un-assignablity of `number` to `A` you need to use [branded types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49432350/how-to-represent-guid-in-typescript/49432424#49432424).

```
type A = number & { isA: undefined};

declare function f(): A;

const a = f(); // `a` is A, not number
```

[play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=7#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UB2BXAtgIwgJygMigG8oBLAZxgC4oUkATCAMxKQjoF8BuAWACg+GAYwA2AQ2zRGtQcBIB7JFEYAKAJTUYPfr0EKywKKIRK1nKAHpzUAAajrpMrAA0yOQdSYcfIA)

Note: There are also a proposals ([this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/33038) and [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/33290)) to have the branded type mechanism baked into typescript but at the time of writing it is not yet finalized.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you can preserve the alias name, while using it like a number

```
interface PreserveAliasName extends Number {}
type A = number & PreserveAliasName;

declare function f(): A;
const a = f(); // `a` is A
const b: A = 5; // allows primitive assign, unlike branded types
const c = BigInt(b); // still allows usage like primitive
```

---

Compared to branded type:

```
type A = number & { __brand: 'A' };
declare function f(): A;
const a = f(); // `a` is A
const b: A = 5;
  Type 'number' is not assignable to type '{ __brand: "A"; }'
const b: A = 5 as A; // needs casting
const c = BigInt(b); // still allows usage like primitive
```

Compared to interface

```
interface A extends Number {}
declare function f(): A;
const a = f(); // `a` is A
const b: A = 5; // allows primitive assign
const c = BigInt(b)
  Argument of type 'A' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number | bigint | boolean'.
const c = BigInt(b as number) // needs casting
```

Comment: You can make `__brand` optional, i.e. `{ __brand?: 'A' }` which wouldn't require casting.