# Typescript query string value to GUID

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on a project in which i've to get string value in (GUID) need to convert in to GUID

Format of the query string is already in GUID but ofcourse when we do take value from query string using angularJS and typescript it's return in to string.

How i can convert that string to GUID.

URL:

https://localhost:44326/search?criteria=apparel&categoryId=c24dee00-ba9d-4af5-b357-a5b20033e5a7

typescript/Angular Code

```
export class Test
{
 categoryId: System.Guid;

init(): void {
     this.categoryId = this.queryString.get("categoryId");
   }
}
```

When this Init() get execute, I am getting error and categoryId set to emtpy without setting up query string value.

Comment: What error are you getting? And I don't think System.Guid is typescript

Comment: Something here may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26501688/a-typescript-guid-class

Answer (score 0):

> I am working on a project in which i've to get string value in (GUID) need to convert in to GUID

There is no native `GUID` type in JavaScript / TypeScript. You are best left representing it as a `string`.

## More

If you are concerned for tracking all the guids you can do

```
type GUID = string;
```

Or even some of the [nominal typing tricks](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/nominalTyping.html).